# Error while building Xampp on Ubunbu 17.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I downloaded Xampp installer on: https://www.apachefriends.org/fr/index.html. I followed instructions to install it on Ubuntu on the Ubuntu official website :
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/xampp

The Instructions are :

-first, I changed my current directory to go to the download folder:

```
cd download
```

- Then i ran:

```
sudo chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```

-I ran this:

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run
```

And I got this error :

```
./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.1-0-installer.run: 1: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.1-0-installer.run: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

What's wrong? Does somebody have an idea ? thank you in advance

Comment: You should *avoid* `sudo` in all the commands above. The only time you need `sudo` is during installation. That is, use `sudo` during `sudo make install`. Maybe `sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run` should be changed to `bash ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run`.

Comment: Try adding \ before * or write entire file name inside single quotes